# Using Selenium with Powershell - Clearing an input field

Tags: .net, powershell, selenium

I'm going crazy with this, so any help provided is apprecaited.

I'm trying to use Selenium 2.44 (.NET 3.5) within Powershell v4. I'm using the ChromeWebDriver, and am using chromedriver.exe v2.13 (found [here](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html)).

```powershell
# Import the Selenium DLLs
Add-Type -Path "C:\mydir\Selenium.WebDriverBackedSelenium.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\mydir\ThoughtWorks.Selenium.Core.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\mydir\WebDriver.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\mydir\WebDriver.Support.dll"

$driver = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver
$driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://my.login.site.com/")

$inputField = $driver.FindElementsById("input_1")
$inputField.SendKeys("My_Search_Query")
```

Everything I have listed there works great. However, as soon as I try to **clear** the input from my `$inputField` variable, I get this error:

```
$inputField.Clear()
##############
Cannot find an overload for "Clear" and the argument count: "0".
At line:1 char:1
+ $inputField.Clear()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

However, if I pipe `$inputField` into the `Get-Member` cmdlet, I can clearly see there is a Clear() method:

```powershell
> $inputField | Get-Member

   TypeName: OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement

Name                                 MemberType Definition
----                                 ---------- ----------
Clear                                Method     void Clear(), void IWebElement.Clear()
Click                                Method     void Click(), void IWebElement.Click()
Equals                               Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
. . .
```

I've tried looking in the `OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions` namespace along with `[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]` namespace, and that doesn't work.

```powershell
$actions = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions($driver)
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$actions.SendKeys($inputField,[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{BACKSPACE}"))

Cannot find an overload for "SendKeys" and the argument count: "2".
At line:1 char:1
+ $actions.SendKeys($inputField,[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{BACKSP ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Very quick look...`FindElementsById`...."elements"? Are you sure it's not returning an array? Should it not be `FindElementById`?

Comment: !%@#$^ Genius!  `FindElementById` returns what I want, an `OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement`, and `FindElementsById` returns a `System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`. Somehow everything was still working, but yes, as soon as I changed it, `Clear()` worked immediately. I've been working on this all damn day! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

I tried this and I think Clear is doing what you expect.

```
$driver.FindElementsById("input_1").Clear
```

Will give you

```
OverloadDefinitions                                        
-------------------                                        
void ICollection[IWebElement].Clear()                      
void IList.Clear()
```

I think clear will be called on the collection and not the element because FindElementsById returns a list.

If you try

```
$driver.FindElementsById("input_1") | % { $_.Clear }
```

Then you will get the Clear method you want.

```
OverloadDefinitions                     
-------------------                     
void Clear()                            
void IWebElement.Clear()
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Might have something to do with the way that you are navigating to your link. This works for me, give it a go.

```
$driver = Start-SeChrome -StartURL "https://my.login.site.com/"
$driver.FindElementById('input_1').SendKeys("My_Search_Query");
$driver.FindElementById('input_1').clear()
```