# How to install Selenium PowerShell eXtensions?

Tags: powershell, selenium

I'm trying to make a PowerShell script( here is the [question about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42370260/powershell-how-can-i-open-an-url-in-existing-browser-tab?noredirect=1#comment71890048_42370260) )

somebody answer me, that I need to install  [Selenium PowerShell eXtensions](https://sepsx.codeplex.com/)

but I doesn't find the manual - "how to install a Selenium PowerShell eXtensions", Somebody please help!

Comment: A quick 5 second Google, lead to some helpful results. (1) https://sepsx.codeplex.com/ (2) https://gist.github.com/Jaykul/d16a390e36ec3ba54cd5e3f760cfb59e 
 (3) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27932786/using-selenium-with-powershell-clearing-an-input-field. Read through these.

Comment: Okay, Where is the installation guide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an install guide specifically for Selenium as it's just a standard powershell module and they are all imported with the same command.

Download the zip from codeplex, extract it and then import the module (substituting the path for yours):

If you call the folder SePSX you can use this:

```
Import-Module "C:\folder\SePSX"
```

Any other name use this:

```
Import-Module "C:\folder\Selenium\SePSX.dll
```

Comment: thank you, but I have an error doing that: Import-Module : Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\lol\SePSX.dll' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not
 supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Module "C:\lol\SePSX.dll"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Import-Module], FileLoadException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileLoadException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand

Comment: I trying to run this command: Import-Module "D:\lol" (all files in "lol" folder) and get Import-Module : The specified module 'D:\lol' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module direc
tory. When I trying to run this: Import-Module "D:\lol\SePSX.dll", I get this error : Import-Module : Could not load file or assembly 'file:///D:\lol\SePSX.dll' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not
 supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)

Comment: may be, it's a better way to do what I want, without selenium and powershell extension? I want to make script that open tab with google.com and after 10 sec. it switch to bing.com in same tab.

Comment: Hey, I found the trouble - must run PS as administrator